# How to extract a value from a Pandas data frame from a reference in the frame, then "walk up" the frame to another specified value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following toy data set:

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

# read the data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
    Date         Return
    1/28/2009   -0.825148
    1/29/2009   -0.859997
    1/30/2009   0.000000
    2/2/2009    -0.909546
    2/3/2009    0.000000
    2/4/2009    -0.899110
    2/5/2009    -0.866104
    2/6/2009    0.000000
    2/9/2009    -0.830099
    2/10/2009   -0.885111
    2/11/2009   -0.878320
    2/12/2009   -0.881853
    2/13/2009   -0.884432
    2/17/2009   -0.947781
    2/18/2009   -0.966414
    2/19/2009   -1.016344
    2/20/2009   -1.029667
    2/23/2009   -1.087432
    2/24/2009   -1.050808
    2/25/2009   -1.089594
    2/26/2009   -1.121556
    2/27/2009   -1.105873
    3/2/2009    -1.205019
    3/3/2009    -1.191488
    3/4/2009    -1.059311
    3/5/2009    -1.135962
    3/6/2009    -1.147031
    3/9/2009    -1.117328
    3/10/2009   -1.009050"""), sep="\s+").reset_index()
```

My goals are to:

a) find the most negative value in the "Return" column

b) find the date the this value occurred

c) then "walk up" the "Return" column to find the **first instance** a specific value (in this case, 0.000000).

d) find the date associated with the value returned in step "c"

The results I'm looking for are:

a) -1.20519

b) March 2, 2009

c) 0.000000

d) February 6, 2009

I can find "a" with the following code:

```
max_dd = df['Maximum_Drawdown'].min()
```

To get "b", I tried to use the following code:

```
df.loc[df['Return'] == max_dd, 'Date']
```

But, the error message says:

```
KeyError: 'Date'
```

**Note:** I can get "b" to work in this toy example, but the actual data throws the error message.  Here is *actual* code used to import the data from the csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(FILE_NAME, parse_dates=True).reset_index()

df.set_index('Date', inplace = True)  <<--- this is causing the problem
```

Comment: Why not january 30th or february 3 for d? they all are equal to 0.

Comment: Edit:  in "C", I'm looking for the FIRST INSTANCE of the value.

Comment: The problem is, is that you have whitespaces in your column names probably. Before everything you do, apply the following: `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` Then try your `.loc` step again

Comment: @Efran -- no, there is no whitespace in the column headers.

Comment: Could you check what `print(df.columns)` returns?

Comment: This `df.loc[df[df['Return'].eq(0)].index.max(), 'Date']` would also get the answer you want in your toy example, not sure if this is also the case for your actual dataset.

Comment: print(df.columns) returns:  Index([u'index', u'Date', u'Return'], dtype='object')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve all of your problems your code could be written as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# read the data
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
    Date         Return
    1/28/2009   -0.825148
    1/29/2009   -0.859997
    1/30/2009   0.000000
    2/2/2009    -0.909546
    2/3/2009    0.000000
    2/4/2009    -0.899110
    2/5/2009    -0.866104
    2/6/2009    0.000000
    2/9/2009    -0.830099
    2/10/2009   -0.885111
    2/11/2009   -0.878320
    2/12/2009   -0.881853
    2/13/2009   -0.884432
    2/17/2009   -0.947781
    2/18/2009   -0.966414
    2/19/2009   -1.016344
    2/20/2009   -1.029667
    2/23/2009   -1.087432
    2/24/2009   -1.050808
    2/25/2009   -1.089594
    2/26/2009   -1.121556
    2/27/2009   -1.105873
    3/2/2009    -1.205019
    3/3/2009    -1.191488
    3/4/2009    -1.059311
    3/5/2009    -1.135962
    3/6/2009    -1.147031
    3/9/2009    -1.117328
    3/10/2009   -1.009050"""), sep="\s+").reset_index()

# a) find the most negative value in the "Return" column
min_value = df["Return"].min()
print("The minimum value in the dataset is: {}".format(min_value))

# b) find the date that this minimum value occurred at
min_value_date = df.iloc[df["Return"].idxmin(), :]["Date"]
print("The minimum value in the dataset occurred on: {}".format(min_value_date))

# c) find the first instance of a specified value in the dataset closest to this
# minimum value with an index less than the minimum value index
found_value = 0
found_indices = df.index[df["Return"] == found_value].tolist()
found_correct_index = -1
for index in found_indices:
    if index > df["Return"].idxmin():
        break
    previous_index = index

found_correct_index = previous_index
try:
    print("The value searched for is {0} and it is found in the index of {1}.".format(found_value, found_correct_index))
except:
    print("The value searched for of {0} was not found in the dataset.".format(found_value))

# d) find the date associated with that value
found_value_date = df.iloc[found_correct_index, :]["Date"]
print("The date associated with that found value of {0} is {1}.".format(found_value, found_value_date))
```

Comment: I want to start at -1.205019 and then "walk up" the "Return" column and grab the first instance of a particular value (in this case, 0.000000).  Then, I want to return the date that this value occurred.  The overall goal is to define a" start date" and an "end date" range and then plot a shaded area coinciding with this date range.

Answer (score 2):

Filter your dataframe for all rows less than the minimum value in Return and also Return equals zero, than show the last value.

```
df.loc[(df.index < df.Return.idxmin()) & (df['Return'] == 0), "Date"].tail(1)
```